# WooCommerce Blocks: Add New Badge to All Products Grid

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Trying to add a NEW badge to the All Products grid within WooCommerce Blocks. Doesn't seem to be incorporating the span element to my code.

This is the PHP I'm currently using:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_blocks_product_grid_item_html', 'add_new_woocommerce_blocks_product_grid_item_html', 10 , 3);
function add_new_desc_woocommerce_blocks_product_grid_item_html($content, $data, $product) {
    $new_badge = '<span class="new-badge onsale">' . esc_html__( 'NEW', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>';
    $after_link_pos = strpos($content, "</a>");
    $before = substr($content, 0, $after_link_pos + 4);
    $after = substr($content, $after_link_pos + 4);

    $content = $before . $new_badge . $after;

    return $content;
}
```